# React & JSX: Nested Object.values inside an HTML Table

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, nested, jsx

I have two objects that I'm converting to arrays via `Object.values().map`. I have a `Material-UI` table and I want to iterate the arrays and display table data from the arrays.

The two arrays are `players` and `stats`. I want to access data from `players` in the first couple of columns in the table, access data from `stats` in the next couple of columns, and then again access data from `players` in the last couple of columns in the form. In other words, `stats` is sandwiched between `players` in the table columns.

Here is what I tried:

```
                    {Object.values(player).map((player, key) => (
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{player[0].primaryNumber}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="left" component="th" scope="row"  className={classes.tableContent}>
                                {player[0].fullName}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{player[0].primaryPosition.name}</TableCell>

                            // Getting an error because this .map is nested inside the player .map
                            {Object.values(stat).map((stat, key) => (
                                <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{stat[0].splits[0].stat.points}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{stat[0].splits[0].stat.goals}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{stat[0].splits[0].stat.assists}</TableCell>
                            ))}
                            <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{player[0].currentAge}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{player[0].height}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{player[0].weight}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{player[0].nationality}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
```

How can I successfully nest the inner `Object.values(stat).map` inside the outer `Object.values(players).map`? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: what is the errror?

Comment: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</> due to the second .map being nested in the first.

Comment: let me know if my answer below works if not there might be something else we could try

Comment: can you post your array and the structure screenshot how do you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do what is stated in the error. Try this;

```
{Object.values(stat).map((stat, key) => (
                                <>
                                  <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{stat[0].splits[0].stat.points}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{stat[0].splits[0].stat.goals}</TableCell>
                                  <TableCell align="left" className={classes.tableContent}>{stat[0].splits[0].stat.assists}</TableCell>
                                </>
                               ))}
```